# Firebug will not open/start

Tags: firefox, firebug

I really hope someone can help me with this, I am stumped!

I had the latest FF and then a defect came in specific to FF ESR. I installed ESR to different directory and created it's own profile so I could use two FF instances side by side. After doing this though Firebug will no longer open/start.

Environment:
Windows 7 -
Firefox 36.0.4 -
Firefox 31.5.3 (ESR) -
Firebug 1.12.8

I have done the following but still won't open:

- Uninstalled both latest and ESR Firefox
- Deleted Mozilla directories in:

  - C:\Program Files (x86)
  - C:\Users\james\AppData\Local
  - C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming
- Ran CCleaner
- Restarted machine
- Fresh install of latest Firefox
- Fresh install of Firebug 1.12.8
- Firebug 1.12.8 didn't work
- Removed Firebug 1.12.8 and installing Firebug 2.0.8
- Same behaviour for Firebug 2.0.8

Still unable to open/start Firebug....

During the fresh install - are there any directories I should have deleted that I didn't?

Any other ideas?

All help will be greatly appreciated!! :)

Thanks all in advance!
James :)

Comment: This is obviously the same question as in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebug/wcYD5Ol-EZE/dLGijPaomNIJ.

Comment: Firefox normally doesn't require to be reinstalled. Profiles can be [deleted and new ones created using the *Profile Manager*](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), which is enough in most cases. Firebug 1.12.x is not maintained anymore and only works in Firefox up to version 32. For Firefox 30+ Firebug 2.0.x is recommended. See the [compatibility table on addons.mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/#addon-description).

Comment: @SebastianZartner - thank you for you response :) It was the first time using the other Google Forum and I was unsure of getting a response, thought I would try here also. Will follow up in Google Forum, that looking like your preferred option. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me but on Windows 10. Following instruction resoved it for me.

1) Follow this instruction: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/uninstall-firefox-from-your-computer

2) Make sure you remove Mozilla in these 2 directories:

-C:\Users\THISUSER\AppData\Local\Mozilla

-C:\Users\THISUSER\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla

3) Restart machine, reinstall firefox and reinstall firebug etc ...

It should work after that. tested.